# Web Scraping through Python using Beautiful Soup is returning none

Tags: html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url='https://bni-india.in/en-IN/chapterdetail?chapterId=P%2BIWaeuOSfF3Mxm03FLSzA%3D%3D&name=BNI+BNI+Alpha'

page=requests.get(url)

soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")


table=soup.find('table',{'class':'table table-hover listtables dataTable no-footer dtr-inline member_list_class'})
print(table)
```

I'm trying to extract the HTML table on the members section on the [following webpage](https://bni-india.in/en-IN/chapterdetail?chapterId=P%2BIWaeuOSfF3Mxm03FLSzA%3D%3D&name=BNI+BNI+Alpha) but it only returns "none"

Comment: It's loaded with javascript - find an api to get the data or use selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://bni-india.in/bnicms/v3/frontend/chapterdetail/display"

data = {
    "pageMode": "Live_Site",
    "chapterId": "P+IWaeuOSfF3Mxm03FLSzA==",
    "languageLocaleCode": "en_IN",
    "website_type": "1",
    "website_id": "13451",
    "mappedWidgetSettings": '[{"key":83,"name":"Chapter+Website","value":"Chapter+Website"},{"key":84,"name":"View+Chapter+Gallery","value":"View+Chapter+Gallery"},{"key":85,"name":"Visit+This+Chapter","value":"Visit+This+Chapter"},{"key":86,"name":"Member+Names","value":"Member+Name"},{"key":87,"name":"Company","value":"Company"},{"key":88,"name":"Profession/Speciality","value":"Profession/Speciality"},{"key":89,"name":"Phone","value":"Phone"},{"key":90,"name":"Send+Mail","value":"Send+Mail"},{"key":91,"name":"Showing","value":"Showing"},{"key":92,"name":"to","value":"to"},{"key":93,"name":"of","value":"of"},{"key":94,"name":"entries","value":"entries"},{"key":95,"name":"Meeting+Details","value":"Meeting+Details"},{"key":96,"name":"View+Map","value":"View+Map"},{"key":97,"name":"Member+Count","value":"Member+Count"},{"key":98,"name":"Show+Members","value":"Show+Members"},{"key":99,"name":"Chapter+Leadership","value":"Chapter+Leadership"},{"key":233,"name":"Directions","value":"Directions"},{"key":307,"name":"Zero+Records","value":"Zero+Records"},{"key":390,"name":"Apply+Now","value":"Apply+Now"}]',
    "planyourvisit": "y",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(url, data=data).content, "html.parser")


df = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one("#DataTables_Table_0")))[0]
cols = ["Member Name", "Company", "Profession/Specialty", "Phone", ""]
df.columns = cols
print(df[cols[:-1]].head().to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Member Name | Company | Profession/Specialty | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aarti Lakhotia | Om Gems & Jewelleers | Retail > Fashion Jewelry | 9004038688 |
| Aditya Goyal | GOYAL BROTHERS | Retail > Fashion Jewelry | 9833311322 |
| ADV.NARENDRA VISHNU SANKPAL | CHAMBER OF ADVOCATE NARENDRA VISHNU SANKPAL | Legal & Accounting > Family Law | +9184 52 039240 |
| Adv. Rajesh Choudhary | RKC Legal | Legal & Accounting > Business Law | 9819000780 |
| Ambika Raj | AMBIKARAJ DESIGNS | Manufacturing > Manufacturing (Other) | 9930908933 |